# Paris Navigo Easy pass for public transport

Tags: tickets, public-transport, france, transportation, paris

I am travelling to Paris and I am confused how to validate the ticket when changing metro or bus. I will be using the [Navigo Easy](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/en/tickets-fares/media/navigo-easy-travel-card) pass.

Below an example of a way I might take. The second option, the **metro 1** then the **bus 47**, so before I enter the metro I validate my ticket then when I change and take the bus Should I validate my ticket again while entering the bus or it will be counted as a new ticket?

Is it enough to validate the ticket only once when I enter the first metro or bus  and then it does not matter how many metro or bus I change?

Or at every metro or bus I take I must scan my Navigo pass?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two different concepts at play here: validation, and tickets.

You have to validate:

- Any time you enter the metro network (by going through a turnstile)
- Any time you enter or exit the RER network (ditto)
- Any time you board a bus or tram (by using the validators near the doors).

A t+ ticket is valid for a single trip across either the metro + RER network (metro currently anywhere, RER inside Zone 1, aka the actual city of Paris), OR across the bus + tram network. There are time limits in each case (counted differently).

Each time you validate, either a new t+ ticket is used (if this is a new trip, or if you switched networks), or the current active ticket is automatically re-used if it’s still valid and you didn’t switch networks.

In your screenshot:

- first itinerary (line 1 then line 7): you validate when you enter the metro station, it will use a single t+ ticket. No further validation.
- second itinerary (line 1 then bus 47): validation when entering the line 1 metro station, then when you board the bus. Two tickets will be used.
- third itinerary (line 1 then RER B): you validate when you enter the line 1 metro station, then when you go from line 1 to RER B, then when you exit RER B, but it will all be on a single t+ ticket.

Note that metro-metro and metro-RER connections must be made within the same station complex, or via one of the approved out-of-station connections.

Comment: You can note that at some huge complexes like Châtelet, changing from a Metro line to another Metro, might require validation (Gare de Lyon too)

Answer (score 5):

> Or at every metro or bus I take I must scan my Navigo pass ?

This, you must validate your card if you change between transport modes (Metro ↔ RER, Metro ↔ Bus/Tram)

For metros, it's easy, you will be forced to validate. For buses and trams, you still need to validate.

Remember that changing between Metro and Bus, counts as a separate ticket for the bus

> ##### Can be used on metro and rail services (train and RER) in Paris
>
> - The Ticket t+ permits ***metro-metro**, **rail-rail** and **metro-rail** connections in Paris for two hours from first validation.
> - It is not valid on trains or RERs outside of Paris.
>
> ##### It can be used on the bus or tram (excluding express tram)
>
> - A single Ticket t+ is valid for the entire trip (with the exception of certain regular lines, see below).
> - It allows connections between **bus and tram** for 90 minutes between the first and the last validation.
> - Please note that the Ticket t+ is not accepted on the express tram

From [IDFM](https://www.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/en/tickets-fares/detail/ticket-t)